# jQuery - div inside div, how to run only 1 click event when inside has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div inside div. If the inside div has been clicked (closeme div), I dont want to run the other div's (container div) click event. How can I do that ?

**html**

```
<div id="container">
content
<div id="closeme"></div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).on('click', '[id="container"]' ,function(){
alert("I am clicked");
}

$(document).on('click', '[id="closeme"]' ,function(){
alert("I am clicked");
}
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/   -  user `event.stoppropagation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '[id="container"]', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("I am container");
})

$(document).on('click', '[id="closeme"]', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("I am closeme");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  content
  <div id="closeme">qwe</div>
</div>
```

Use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to put closeme function before the container function ? Because if container gets the click event first (even if user clicks the closeme), it stops and never run the closeme function ?

Comment: i doubt the order affect that

Answer (score 2):

Do a if to test if the target is `#closeme`

```
 $(document).on('click', '[id="closeme"]', function(event) {
     if ($(event.target).is('[id="closeme"]')) {
        alert("coloseme clicked");
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have just mentioned. You have to stop the event propagation. Here is a full working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    content
    <div id="closeme">Inner Div</div>
  </div>
</body>
  <script>
    $(document).on('click', '[id="container"]', function(event) {
      alert("container clicked");
    });

    $(document).on('click', '[id="closeme"]', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      alert("coloseme clicked");
    });
  </script>
</html>
```